# How can I update each row with a different value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I thought I could do this with a WHILE LOOP but it updates all rows each time through.

I have a table where I need to update two fields with unique id using the application unique value functions.  The function gives me a GUID (Trans) and another gives me a unique Trans_ID.  I need to update each row with these unique IDs.

I will update one row, run the function to get the next unique numbers and then populate the next row.  I can't figure out how to do this.

```
        DECLARE @RowCount as INT
        DECLARE @IntFlag as INT
        SET     @IntFlag = 1
        SELECT  @RowCount = count(*) from trans_periodic_retainer_final
        DECLARE @TransID as char(20)                                    
        DECLARE @BatchID uniqueidentifier
        WHILE   @IntFlag <=@RowCount
        BEGIN

            /* Functions to get the unique values */
            UPDATE Increments SET Increment = Increment+1 WHERE v7Tables = 'Transactions' AND Site = 'TESTSERVER'
            SET @BatchID = newid()
            SELECT @TransID = Increment FROM Increments WHERE v7Tables = 'Transactions'         AND Site = 'TESTSERVER'

            UPDATE Transactions set trans = @BatchId, Trans_id = @TransID

            SET @IntFlag = @intFlag +1
        END
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where are these unique values coming from?

Comment: What query did you try, and what happened? How is the target table defined?

Comment: each row need to be uniquely identifiable (usually with a primary key). then you can do `update table set a=x where k=y`

Comment: Please give the function definition and the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the one I can think of now, try and let me know.

```
DECLARE Tran_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM Transactions
OPEN Tran_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Tran_Cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     UPDATE Increments SET Increment = Increment+1 WHERE v7Tables = 'Transactions' AND Site = 'TESTSERVER'
     SET @BatchID = newid()
     SELECT @TransID = Increment FROM Increments WHERE v7Tables = 'Transactions' AND Site = 'TESTSERVER'

     UPDATE Transactions set trans = @BatchId, Trans_id = @TransID  WHERE CURRENT OF Tran_Cursor
     SET @IntFlag = @intFlag +1
FETCH NEXT FROM Tran_Cursor
END
CLOSE Tran_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Tran_Cursor
```

If you dont want to update the records already having unique ID then you can replace the the following statement

```
DECLARE Tran_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM Transactions
```

with the following

```
DECLARE Tran_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE Trans_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly first time!  I appreciate you taking time to write this bit of code for me.    - Steve (Chicago)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to update the Transactions Table. In that case you are missing where clause in the update statement, and also I have a question which column you can use in the where clause.?

```
UPDATE Transactions set trans = @BatchId, Trans_id = @TransID WHERE (IdentityColum) = Value.
```

Comment: I am updating the Transaction table. I don't know what I could use in the where clause since I'm trying to update the fields with the unique values. I have 5 rows in the table. I want the code to go to the first row, update it. Go to the next row, update that one until it gets to the end.

Comment: Then in that case try using cursor.! Can you send me the Transactions table structure so that I can try writing that for you (If you are not sure how to use cursor.)

Comment: Thanks @Muthu.  I have used a cursor once many many years ago in Oracle.  The table structure is basically Transaction(varchar(60), Transid(int), Value(numeric(10,4)), initials(varchar(10)).  I already have values in value and initials.  I just need to add the values in Transaction and Transid.